# How to make a clip-path animation transition gradually on unhover in CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I have these two clip-path animations

```css
@keyframes animation1 {
    0% ,
    100% {
        clip-path: polygon(
            0% 45%,
            16% 44%,
            33% 50%,
            54% 60%,
            70% 61%,
            84% 59%,
            100% 52%,
            100% 100%,
            0% 100%
        );
    }
    50% {
        clip-path: polygon(
            0% 60%,
            15% 65%,
            34% 66%,
            51% 62%,
            67% 50%,
            84% 45%,
            100% 46%,
            100% 100%,
            0% 100%
        );
    }
}

@keyframes hoverAnimation {
    
    0%,
    100% {
        clip-path: polygon(
            0% 40%,
            16% 39%,
            33% 45%,
            54% 55%,
            70% 56%,
            84% 54%,
            100% 47%,
            100% 100%,
            0% 100%
        );
    }
    50% {
        clip-path: polygon(
            0% 0%,
            16% 0%,
            33% 0%,
            54% 0%,
            70% 0%,
            84% 0%,
            100% 0%,
            100% 100%,
            0% 100%
        );
    }
}
```

and I have these css properties for my items.

```css
object { 
    color: azure; 
    animation: animation1 6s ease-in-out infinite;   
    transition: all 1s; 
}
object:hover { 
    animation: hoverAnimation 5s ease-in-out;     
    transition: all 1s;   
}
```

And it works exactly as expected on hover; I like how it looks. However, when mousing off the object, it simply snaps immediately back into animation1, when I want it to play hoverAnimation in reverse to make this change gradual.
Why is it doing this, and is there any way to fix it?
Thank you so much.